# AngularJS get with parameter

Tags: angularjs

actually I do not develop with angularJS, currently somethimes it seems to me that I fight with Angular :-) therefore sorry for my question.

I have the following code to get user from rest service:

```
services.factory('GetUserByUsernameService', function($resource) {
return $resource('users/findUserByUsername/:username',{username:   'admin'});
});
```

and the invokation looks like this:

```
function UpdateUserController($scope, GetUserByUsernameService) {
$scope.findUser = function() {
    $scope.foundedUser = GetUserByUsernameService.get();
 }
```

}

username is a path parameter. now actually I do not know how to set this parameter from the get- invokation method (GetUserByUsernameService.get()) to the return $resource('... invokation.
Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do:

`$scope.foundedUser = GetUserByUsernameService.get({username:user});`

in your controller code